# How do I fix 'unparsable' sqlfluff lint error

Tags: dbt, sqlfluff

I am receiving the error `L:   3 | P:   1 |  PRS | Found unparsable section:`.

This is when I am calling the date_spine macro provide by dbt_utils. Has anyone come across this before and what expected value to set in the definition of the macro in sqlfluff?

See as follows for defining macro in sqlfluff file in dbt:

`date_spine = {% macro date_spine(datepart, start_date, end_date) %}'HERE'{% endmacro %}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set `date_spine =` portion, just define the macro as:

```
{% macro date_spine(datepart, start_date, end_date) %}'HERE'{% endmacro %}
```